# Targeting Nested Elements in a List that have the Same Class Attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm just learning CSS, and I can't seem to solve this problem.  The HTML looks like this:

```
`<section class=”red”>
  <ul>
     <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
     <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class=”red”>
  <ul>
    <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
    <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class=”blue”>
  <ul>
    <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
    <li class=”list-one”>item</li>
  </ul>
</section>`
```

I'm trying to target/style the list items with the class attribute of 'blue.'  I've tried .blue{color:red}, and .blue ul li {color:red} and some other combinations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - use straight quotes for attributes, not curly quotes (good rule of thumb, never use curly quotes in programming except inside of strings, and even then they can break things)

Comment: Thank you!  I've adjusted the quotes in the HTML markup based on your recommendation, and now the CSS selector .blue{color:red} is working and targeting the `<li>` nested in the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`”` quotes invalid for HTML. You can try with `'` or `"`

```html
<style>
.blue ul li {
  color:blue;
}

.red ul li {
  color:red;
}
</style>

<section class="red">
  <ul>
     <li class="list-one">item</li>
     <li class="list-one">item</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="red">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-one">item</li>
    <li class="list-one">item</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="blue">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-one">item</li>
    <li class="list-one">item</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful.  It also appears that I can target the `<li>` nested under the `<section>` with the class attribute of `blue` by just writing `.blue {color:red]`